# jQuery Validation plugin "a.validator.methods[d] is undefined"

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I want to know how to validate a file size, type and extension using the plugins from http://jqueryvalidation.org.

I'm trying to make the `<input type="file" name="file">` not required but I get a `a.validator.methods[d] is undefined` in my console.Everything works fine if `file:{required:` is `true`. But in my case, a file is not required.

I have these files included:

```
<script src="../javascripts/jquery.validation.js"></script>
<script src="../javascripts/jquery.validation.additional.js"></script>

$('#message').validate({
    ignore: "",
    rules: {
        message:{ required: true },
        file:{ required:false, accept: "png|jpe?g|gif", filesize: 1048576 }
    },
    messages:{
        message:"Please type your message",
        file:{ required:"File is required", accept: "Hello" },
    }
});
```

UPDATE:

I tried using `ignore: ".ignore"` with `file:{required:true` and `<input type="file" name="file" class="ignore">`. It still validates on submit. And if I set `file:{required:` to `false` then I still get a `a.validator.methods[d] is undefined` error in console.

Comment: Can you add more codes and format to display results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at Ignore from Documentation.
http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate

Comment: How would I use it in my case. `ignore: "file"`. Do I use the name attribute or class?

Comment: Doesn't work. I added `ignore: ".ignore"` and `.ignore` class to the input

Comment: Both will Work. If you use the Name Attribute every file element in your Form will be ignored. A Class will be more effective if you want to validate another file Element in the future.

Comment: Though the your link might offer the solution to the question, link only questions are not encouraged. Please read about how to write a good answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Use it like this: Ignore:"file" or add a class tho the specific file Element and try this: Ignore:".theFileClass"

Comment: I did, but it is still validating on submit